# Как записать изображение в текст?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возможно глупый вопрос, но как записать изображение в текстовый файл? Для некоторого проекта понадобилось хранить изображение в тексте, но чтобы питон мог с ним работать и переводить обратно в .png. Возможно ли это?

Comment: я конечно дико извиняюсь, но что нужно употребить, чтобы хранить ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЕ в ТЕКСТОВОМ файле?))))

Comment: @Inventor, Поверьте, вам лучше не знать)

Comment: Закодировать изображение в BASE64

Comment: @gil9red, перенесите свой комментарий в ответы, чтоб я его отметил решением

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Закодируйте изображение в `base64` и сохраните в файл.

Для этого используйте модуль `base64`:

- `base64.b64encode` -- для кодирования байтов в `base64` (результат в байтах)
- `base64.b64decode` -- для раскодирования байтов из `base64` (результат в байтах)

Пример:

```
import base64

file_name_img = 'img.jpg'
file_name_txt = 'img.txt'

with open(file_name_img, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

with open(file_name_txt, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(base64.b64encode(data))

# Раскодирование из base64
with open(file_name_txt, 'rb') as f:
    img_data = base64.b64decode(f.read())
    print(img_data[:100])  # Первые 100 байт
```